# I am writing a simple client socket application but after the connection the server is receiving an empty buffer

Tags: c++, sockets, server, client

this is a simple client socket application. when i run this code, the server when receives data, is receiving an empty buffer. can anyone find a problem?
The code is written in cpp using sockets to transfer data.
after the connection, the client is supposed to send "Hello im client" to the server, and the server prints the message, but something is wrong in the way.

this is the server code

```
#define IP "127.0.0.1"


int ConnectServer::connectTo()
{

    //----------------------
    // Initialize Winsock
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult = 0;

    _ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    sockaddr_in serverAddr;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != NO_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"WSAStartup() failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Create a SOCKET for listening for incoming connection requests.
    _ListenSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (_ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        wprintf(L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
    // IP address, and port for the socket that is being bound.
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    iResult = bind(_ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)& serverAddr, sizeof(serverAddr));
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"bind function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        iResult = closesocket(_ListenSocket);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    //----------------------
    // Listen for incoming connection requests 
    // on the created socket
    if (listen(_ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        wprintf(L"listen function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(_ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for accepting incoming requests.
    SOCKET AcceptSocket;
    sockaddr_in client;


    wprintf(L"Waiting for client to connect...\n");

    //----------------------
    // Accept the connection.
    int clientSize = sizeof(client);

    AcceptSocket = accept(_ListenSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&client, &clientSize);
    if (AcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        wprintf(L"accept failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(_ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {

        wprintf(L"Client connected.\n");

    }
    //cout << "whats happening??" << endl;
    char* buffer = "";
    iResult = recv(AcceptSocket, buffer, (int)strlen(buffer), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("recv function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(_server);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("recieved data:\n");
        printf(buffer);
    }




    iResult = closesocket(_ListenSocket);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl;
    }
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

this is the client code:

```
int ConnectClient::connectTo()
{
    int iResult;
    WSADATA WSAData;
    SOCKET _server;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    HBITMAP pic = NULL;
    WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 0), &WSAData);
    _server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(IP);
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(PORT);

    if (connect(_server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        wprintf(L"connect function failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        system("PAUSE");
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        std::cout << "Connected to _server!" << std::endl;
        char  *Buffer = "hello I'm client";
        printf(Buffer);
        iResult = send(_server, Buffer, (int)strlen(Buffer), 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(_server);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    }

    //cout << testBuffer << endl;
    //cout << strlen(testBuffer) << endl;



    //coordinations(_server);
    iResult = closesocket(_server);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        wprintf(L"closesocket function failed with error %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Client disconnected" << std::endl;
    }

    WSACleanup();
    std::cout << "Socket closed." << std::endl << std::endl;
    system("PAUSE");

    return 0;
}

int ConnectClient::coordinations(SOCKET server)
{

    HANDLE hStdInput, hStdOutput, hEvent;                         //WAIT_ABANDONED   = 128
    INPUT_RECORD ir[128];                                       //WAIT_OBJECT_0    = 0
    DWORD nRead;                                                //WAIT_TIMEOUT     = 258
    COORD xy;
    UINT i;

    hStdInput = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    hStdOutput = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    FlushConsoleInputBuffer(hStdInput);
    hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL);                  //Event is created non-signaled (3rd param).
    HANDLE handles[2] = { hEvent, hStdInput }; 
    //char testBuffer[1024];    
    char a;
    char b;
    //Program loops monitoring two handles.  The
    while (WaitForMultipleObjects(2, handles, FALSE, INFINITE))     //1st handle ( handles(0) ) is an event which
    {                                                           //is initially set to non-signaled.  The 2nd
        ReadConsoleInput(hStdInput, ir, 128, &nRead);                 //handle monitored by WaitForMultipleObjects()
        for (i = 0; i<nRead; i++)                                       //is the standard input handle set up to
        {                                                          //allow access to mouse/keyboard input.  As
            switch (ir[i].EventType)                                //long as neither handle is in a signaled
            {                                                      //state, WaitForMultipleObjects() will block
            case KEY_EVENT:                                       //in an efficient wait state.  If any keypress
                if (ir[i].Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode == VK_ESCAPE) //or mouse movement occurs, WaitForMultiple
                    SetEvent(hEvent);                                //Objects will return TRUE and the input will
                else                                                //be read by ReadConsolInput().  If the [ESCAPE]
                {                                                   //key is pressed the event object represented
                    xy.X = 0; xy.Y = 0; 
                    //by hEvent will be set to a signaled state by
                    SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOutput, xy);         //the SetEvent() Api function.  This will be
                    printf                                           //picked up by the next WaitForMultipleObjects()
                        (    
                        //call, and the function will return FALSE and
                        "AsciiCode = %d: symbol = %c\n",                //execution will drop out of the while loop
                        ir[i].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar,           //and program termination will occur.
                        ir[i].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar
                        );     
                    a = ir[i].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
                    b = ir[i].Event.KeyEvent.uChar.AsciiChar;
                    char testBuffer[1024] = "AsciiCode = %d: symbol = %c\n", a, b;              //execution will drop out of the while loop
                                 //and program termination will occur.

                    send(server, testBuffer, strlen(testBuffer), 0);//It is important to note that if the 3rd
                }                                                   //parameter to WaitForMultipleObjects() is
                break;                                              //set to FALSE, the function will return if
            case MOUSE_EVENT:                                     //either of the handles in the HANDLE array
                xy.X = 0, xy.Y = 1;                                     //represented by handles is signaled.
                SetConsoleCursorPosition(hStdOutput, xy);
                printf
                    (
                    "%.3d\t%.3d\t%.3d",
                    ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X,
                    ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y,
                    (int)ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwButtonState & 0x07   //mask out scroll wheel, which screws up
                    );     //output
                a = ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.X;
                b = ir[i].Event.MouseEvent.dwMousePosition.Y;
                char testBuffer[1024] = "AsciiCode = %d: symbol = %c\n", a, b;              //execution will drop out of the while loop
                //and program termination will occur.

                send(server, testBuffer, strlen(testBuffer), 0);
                break;
            }
        }
    };

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you thought to use boost asio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
char* buffer = "";
iResult = recv(AcceptSocket, buffer, (int)strlen(buffer), 0);
```

You're telling `recv` to read zero bytes, as `buffer` is empty.

On top of this there are a couple of problems with the code. You're sending a string like this:

```
iResult = send(_server, Buffer, (int)strlen(Buffer), 0);
```

Which will send all the characters, but not the null terminator. However, your server code is expecting a null terminator as it is printing the code via `printf`.

A more significant problem is how you are sending the data. Your server has no idea how much data is coming from the client, so unless it reads a byte at a time until it gets a null terminator (which is hugely inefficient) its got problems.

The usual approach to this is to send a message header of a fixed size and have the server read the header. One of the fields in the header will contain the length of the message body, and once the server has read the header it can allocate memory for the message body and then read it.